# XMLStreamException occurs when invoking a .NET ASMX (Soap) web service using JAX-WS

Tags: jax-ws

I am trying to call a .NET web service using NetBeans. One of my web method returns a complex type and Java is throwing an exception while processing the response. The exception message is: "Content is not allowed in prolog".

Using Fiddler, I was able to see the exact response that the web service gives, and I believe that the problem lies in the UTF-8 BOM sequence (EF BB BF) at the beginning of the content.

I found a similar question on Stack Overflow regarding the BOM sequence and invoking Java Web Services from .NET, but nothing on the reverse scenario.

1) Is this something that JAX-WS can handle?

2) If not, is it possible to control and disable the outputting of the UTF-8 BOM? I tried setting the Response ContentEncoding to omit the UTF-8 BOM by adding the following line in my Global.asax at the start of every request: `Response.ContentEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this answer comes a bit late, but as I faced the same problem and no clear answer came up, here is my solution:

Instead of using the standard implementation by Oracle, which is used by default, use [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org). You only need to add the required libraries to the classpath. The classloader then loads Apache CXF instead of the Oracle one and your are done. I didn't have to change any line of code.

If you are using Maven, this artifact adds the necessary (client) libs of Apache CXF:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
  <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for taking the time to resurrect this very old question and provide an answer. Fortunately for me I no longer have to deal with Java and SOAP with our product, but i'm sure other people will appreciate the answer!

Comment: @Gabriel: You're welcome! It was so frustrating to find no answer, especially if some people had this very same problem. And as I needed to find the solution, it was only logical to me to post an answer.